# Make the list box in the masked back ground visible

Tags: html, css

I have a masked back ground and a drop down behind the scenes. Currently it is appearing like:

[image]

It must appear like:

[image]

The html is as below:

```html
<div id="suggest" style="position: fixed; border: 1px solid rgb(168, 168, 168); width: 304px;" data-sap-ui-area="suggest">
        <div id="__list0" data-sap-ui="__list0" data-sap-ui-fastnavgroup="true" tabindex="-1" style="width:100%" class="sapMList sapMListBGSolid">
            <div id="__list0-before" tabindex="-1"></div><ul role="listbox" id="__list0-listUl" tabindex="0" class="sapMListModeNone sapMListShowSeparatorsAll sapMListUl">
                <li id="__item0-__list0-0" data-sap-ui="__item0-__list0-0" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="__text4" class="common-txt-align-left sapMLIB sapMLIB-CTX sapMLIBShowSeparator sapMLIBTypeActive sapMSLI">
                    <div class="sapMLIBContent" id="__item0-__list0-0-content">
                        <div class="sapMSLIDiv sapMSLITitleDiv">
                            <div class="sapMSLITitleOnly">TOI_1770089305</div>
                        </div><div class="sapMSLIDescriptionDiv">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="__list0-after" tabindex="0"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Edit - The masking is done by a div with the following css class:

```
.common-opaqueDom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1199;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}
```

Comment: I have no idea how does your code look like, but I guess there should be changed css z-index propety

Comment: Provide proper code.

Comment: try to increase z-index of input and set "position: relative"

Comment: You should add all your code, this means css, js and other libraries you use in yor project. Not only a little html snippet

Comment: Please find the css - "common-opaqueDom" of the div  element that masks the background as mentioned in this post. It has a z index of 1199. I tried giving a z index greater or lesser than 1199 to the div element with id "suggest", it does not work. Should i give z-index to any other element?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#suggest{
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: Tried z -index on elements it does not work. Please refer to the css as mentioned in the post for the masking element that masks the suggestion list items in the background.